# how to achieve currency type Input in angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, input, currency-formatting

I want following thing to happen in my **angular 5** application.

I am having **text box** where i am inputting **numeric values**, as soon as focus of that text box is lost, Numeric values i entered should be formatted to ***currency*** with '$' and ',','.' symbols. how to achieve this?

I want to show my input numeric values as in below picture.

[image]

Comment: I have added solution on stackblitz pleas check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qprls8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way..! I installed a package in my angular 5 application which provides this functionality.

I have done in this way.

**npm install currency-formatter --save**

Code of .html is as follows:

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="taxableValue" (blur)="formatCurrency_TaxableValue($event)">
```

here on blur of text box i am calling **"formatCurrency_TaxableValue($event)"** function.

Code of .ts file is as below.

```html
formatCurrency_TaxableValue(event)
  {
    var uy = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US',{style: 'currency', currency:'USD'}).format(event.target.value);
    this.tax = event.target.value;
    this.taxableValue = uy;
  }
```

this way it worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

Here you need `CurrencyPipe` transform on (blur) event.

In your `app.module.ts` add `CurrencyPipe` provider.

```
import { CommonModule, CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  ... 
  providers: [CurrencyPipe]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**App.component.html**

Bind event `onblur` event to input textbox.

```
<h1>On Focus lost change Format amount</h1>
<input type="text"(blur)="transformAmount($event)" [(ngModel)]="formattedAmount"  />
```

In your `App.component.ts` file write method `transformAmount($event)`

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import { Component,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
 formattedAmount;
 amount;
   constructor(private currencyPipe : CurrencyPipe) {
  }

   transformAmount(element){
      this.formattedAmount = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.formattedAmount, '$');

      element.target.value = this.formattedAmount;
  }
}
```

**See this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qprls8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Hope above solution will help you!

Comment: Thank you. this is really helpful. but i am getting output like 'USD456,132.00' i.e, instead of '$' symbol i am getting 'USD'.

Comment: If you seet stackblitz demo there you will get the what you want to achieve

Comment: i observed many people facing same issue. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16374 . For now i have done like this ->                                                                                
 this.houseHoldIncome = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.houseHoldIncome, 'USD').replace("USD", "$");

Comment: instead of doing like that just replace the 'USD' to '$' this will help

Answer (score 1):

Here text box will show how you are expecting.

```
<input name="money" type="text" value="{{amount | number :'1.2-2' | currency }}" [(ngModel)]="amount"/>
```

Comment: This does not work at all.